# How to make this grid work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, grid

I purchased a html5 theme that I am customizing for my church website. It has two cool features:

1. A tab script that allows for multiple items to displayed on one page.
2. a grid that will allow me to display sermons in a series in a neat and orderly way.

Both of these work well when used alone, but when I try to use the grid inside the tabs, no dice.
I am a design guy and know very little about Javascript functions and need help. Here is what the developer, who has not got back with me said to do:

"The grid function is built to run on page load and when you put it inside a tab it doesn’t initialize on page load so don’t work when you change tabs. A custom function needs to be built for this which will run the isotope grid on tabs change. Like:"

```
$(".nav-tabs li")click(function(e){
ADORE.IsoTope();
e.preventDefault();
}
```

I do not know where to add this or even if something else needs to be added. I have also attached a link where you can download my code (html/php and .js file) so you can see what is going on. Any help would be appreciated. Remember, I know very little about Javascript.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jypfjz3a89soxh7/example.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
$(".nav-tabs li a").click(function(e){
        $('a[href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]').tab('show');
        var IsoTopeCont = $(".isotope-grid");
            IsoTopeCont.isotope({
                itemSelector: ".grid-item",
                layoutMode: 'sloppyMasonry'
        });
    });
```

at Line 469 of your init.js and it should work for you. Thanks

Comment: Ok, there is another problem. When I click back on tab one it does not go back to it. For example if I click on tab 2 and try to go back to tab 1 it stays on tab 2. Otherwise, it works.

Comment: Ok I got the tabs working, it was a mismatch of the a tag id's. I had it as 2011 in the nav tabs div and 1 on the first tab content div. It couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following: inside your init.js add the following:

```
$(".nav-tabs li").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   ADORE.IsoTope(); 
});
```

e.g. in the first line after `var ADORE = window.ADORE || {};`
As you mentioned that you don't know much about javascript: the first line starts with

```
jQuery(function($){ ...
```

This takes care about that everything inside the `{` will get executed when jQuery is loaded.
I'm not sure if the `e.preventDefault();` is necessary - this is used e.g. to prevent links from getting executed and attach a different function to the `click()` event, so it could be possible that Isotope is working when a tab is clicked, but the tab is not working anymore.

If this won't work, you can check with web dev tools if there are any script errors. In case you're unfamiliar with web dev tools, find some details for Firefox here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console and for Chrome here: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console

Comment: Well I thought it worked... I tested it on Safari and it worked for a minute, but on refresh it stopped working and will not work on Chrome or Firefox. Here is my updated js file. Any suggestions. https://www.dropbox.com/s/tf2c5xkjg65hdkh/init.js?dl=0

Comment: Also I used the Chrome console and the only error it found in the init.js file is: if($(body).hasClass(no-touch) & $(window).width() > 992) {. Which I guess has to do with the responsive layout, and not with the tabs.